# Можно ли как нибудь отключить «notify if debug session was finished without being paused» сразу для всех проектов, а не для одного?

Tags: phpstorm

Эта функция выдает уведомления, если скрипт сайта отработал без остановки на точках останова. Мне не нравятся эти уведомления. В каждом проекте приходится отключать эту функцию. Можно ли как-нибудь отключить сразу для всех? В том числе и для тех, которые еще не существуют. То есть, они (проекты) будут создаваться с уже выключенной функцией.

Comment: Можно. просто откройте настройки PHPstorm из окна запуска не открывая никакой проект. Тогда сможете выбрать настройки для всех новых проектов.